# Create ContentVersion via CLI generating argument list too long

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-error, powershell

After generating a report via shell command and I trying to store that file using sfdx into content version in salesforce using below codes :

```
local html=$( base64 PMDReport.html )   
sfdx force:data:record:create -s ContentVersion -v "VersionData=$html Title='PMD_Report' ContentDocumentId='069MT0000008SIfYAM' PathOnClient='Report.html' Origin='H'"
echo "created document from report successfully"
```

When executing the sfdx command using a static versionData value like bXktc3RyaW5n the code is working fine. But when getting a base64 content from a file and using it in the command I am getting :

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/sfdx: Argument list too long
```

Comment: It seems that problem is not in command itself, but rather in the OS limits of length of command arguments. Check this for inspiration -- https://haydenjames.io/bash-usr-bin-rm-argument-list-too-long-solution/. A possible solution for this could be to use custom sfdx plugin --  https://github.com/mshanemc/shane-sfdx-plugins#sfdx-shanedatafileupload--f-filepath--c--p-id--n-string--u-string---apiversion-string---json---loglevel-tracedebuginfowarnerrorfataltracedebuginfowarnerrorfatal (not affiliated with it)